# JAXB: ConnectException when reading in local file because DTD could not be loaded

Tags: java, https, jaxb, certificate

I am trying to read in a local XML-File using JaxB. This XML-File contains a Link to a DTD, which is using HTTPS (I can't turn that of). 
The Problem is, that in my Company we are behind an HTTP-Proxy which inserts its own Certificate. I guess my Bosses want to make sure we are not wasting time on Heise or something. 
Of course JAXB doesn't recognise this as a valid certificate, and gives me a java.net.ConnectException.
I trust the URL, how can I skip the Certificate-Checking?

Here is a minimal Example of the Problem:

The XML:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
   <!DOCTYPE hallo SYSTEM  "https://www.example.com/my.dtd" >
   <xmlroot>
      <name>John Peel</name>
   </xmlroot>
```

And the Code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

public class JaxBTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "12.34.56.78");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");

            XmlRoot var = JAXB.unmarshal( new File("bla.xml"), XmlRoot.class );
            System.out.println("var: "+var.name);
    }
}

@XmlRootElement
class XmlRoot
 {
@XmlElement( name = "name" )
 public String name;
 }
```

Comment: 'an HTTP-Proxy which inserts its own Certificate' - sounds strange... please show the full stacktrace of ConnectException including the message text.

Comment: The point is most probably, that when we visit an encrypted Webpage the Proxy acts as a man-in-the-middle so they can decrypt the connection an look what we are doing